# Enabling Ajax on Sharepoint

Tags: .net, ajax, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, ajax.net

**What I have?**

I have installed Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 on my PC to work on it locally. I deployed an external Web Part which loads RSS feeds and shows the posts' titles, links and descriptions ([RSS Advanced Reader Web Part for SharePoint](http://wssrssreader.codeplex.com/)).

**What problem am I facing?**

On my machine with WSS 3.0, the Web Part does not work where I had an error message "Ajax is not currently enabled."

Has anyone faced problems like this and found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

[Web.Config entries for enabling AJAX for SharePoint 2007](http://zieglers.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/webconfig-entries-for-enabling-ajax-for-sharepoint-2007/)